# Buttons with answer method on iOS with sqlite?

Tags: ios, sqlite, random

I am trying to proceed with my quiz game on iOS but I have a problem. I successfully created the sqlite array and the random question and answers but now I can't imagine how to create the answer method. In my sqlite table on every question the answer1 column is the right answer. So how can I create a method to check for the correct answer with buttons? Above is the random questions and random answers code.

```
 -(NSMutableArray *) categoriesList{
categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
@try {
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Categories.sqlite"];
    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

    }


    const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE Category IS 2 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }else{

        while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {

            Categories * choise = [[Categories alloc] init];
            question.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 1)];
            NSMutableArray  *arary = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            while (arary.count < 4) {
                int value = arc4random()%4+2;
                BOOL isFound = [[arary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"intValue == %d",value]]] count];
                if(!isFound)
                    [arary addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:value]];                   
            }
            answer1.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, [[arary objectAtIndex:0] intValue])];
            answer2.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, [[arary objectAtIndex:1] intValue])];
            answer3.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, [[arary objectAtIndex:2] intValue])];
            answer4.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, [[arary objectAtIndex:3] intValue])];

            [categories addObject:choise];

        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
@finally {

    sqlite3_close(db);

    return categories;
}
```

And here is my try to create an answer method.

```
- (IBAction)answer1:(id)sender {    
if([answer1.text isEqualToString:@"2"])
{
    NSLog(@"Correct");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Incorrect");
}
}

- (IBAction)answer2:(id)sender {    
if([answer2.text isEqualToString:@"2"])
{
    NSLog(@"Correct");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Incorrect");
}
}
- (IBAction)answer3:(id)sender {    
if([answer3.text isEqualToString:@"2"])
{
    NSLog(@"Correct");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Incorrect");
}
}
- (IBAction)answer4:(id)sender {
if([answer4.text isEqualToString:@"2"])
{
    NSLog(@"Correct");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Incorrect");
}
}
```

Can please someone help how to create the correct answer method with the four buttons?

Comment: For a start, you're treating `numbers` as if it has values from 2-to-5 in one place and 1-to-4 in another.  Assuming you fix that, what's it doing now vs. what you want it to do?

Comment: The random 2-5 numbers that i have created is because i pull them from the table with the answers. So i needed them to represent on the four labels. So now i want the four button actions to check for the correct answer which in my case is the answer with the number 2. How can i make it to work?

Comment: Please don't significantly edit your question after you have received an answer as they are then answering a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question should be more descriptive, but as I understand it your database is not structured. You have to use normalization on Db. Like Tables structure should be like:
tablename: Question(questionId,QuestionTitle,CorrectOptionId,categoryId)
tableName: Option(optionId,QuestionId,OptionTitle)
To pic random question query should be:@"SELECT * FROM Question WHERE Category IS 2 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1"
You can use Model Class for Question.
so to pic answers from DB: @"select * from option where questionId = %d",questionObj.questionId.
you can shuffle you option array.
create random buttons for option and set optionBTN.tag = optionObj.optionId.
and on the click on optionBTN compare optionBTN.tag == questionObj.CorrectOptionId , if it is equal means it is correct ans.

I think you will understand my logic. I have already implemented in a project and it is working fine.
If you have any query please let me know.

Edits:
I think this code will help you:

```
NSMutableArray  *arary = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    while (arary.count < 4) {
        int value = arc4random()%4+2;
        BOOL isFound = [[arary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"intValue == %d",value]]] count];
        if(!isFound)
            [arary addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:value]];
    }
```

**Updates:**
Replace This code:

```
while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {

            Categories * choise = [[Categories alloc] init];
            question.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 1)];
            NSMutableArray  *arary = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            while (arary.count < 4) {
                int value = arc4random()%4+2;
                BOOL isFound = [[arary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"intValue == %d",value]]] count];
                if(!isFound)
                    [arary addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:value]];
                answer1.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, value)];
                answer2.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, value)];
                answer3.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, value)];
                answer4.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, value)];
            }
```

BY:

```
while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {

            Categories * choise = [[Categories alloc] init];
            question.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement, 1)];
            NSMutableArray  *arary = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            while (arary.count < 4) {
                int value = arc4random()%4+2;
                BOOL isFound = [[arary filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"intValue == %d",value]]] count];
                if(!isFound)
                    [arary addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:value]];
          }
               //place this code outside while loop.
                answer1.text = [NSSTring stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[array objectAtIndex:0] intValue]];//you can use exception handling here.
                answer2.text = [NSSTring stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[array objectAtIndex:1] intValue]];;
                answer3.text = [NSSTring stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[array objectAtIndex:2] intValue]];
                answer4.text = [NSSTring stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[array objectAtIndex:3] intValue]];
```

Comment: Thank you my friend for your logic. I really cannot understand what you mean. In my case i have two tables, the first is with two columns (ID), and (Names) which is the names of the categories and the second Table has a foreign key to the first table on the (ID) and then the Columns (Question), (Answer 1), (Answer 2), (Answer 3), (Answer 4). So if someone choose one category that loads the questions with the same ID and it's answers. In your case i really don't understand the approach. Can you saw me the code of your project?

Comment: Yes Ofcourse, give me your emailId I will share my database and code with you.

Comment: How can i tell you my email Prateek not here on comments?

Comment: prateekprem@gmail.com my emailID

Comment: prateek i edited my first code with your code. If you can, take a look on my edit.It really works but my result is that i have from value only one number.How can i use the other three on answer.text fields?And my friend ignore my email question. Thank you again.

Comment: i am getting this error now my friend: -[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x863d250
2013-06-15 21:07:31.978 Diplomatiki[823:c07] Problem with prepare statement:  unknown error

Comment: please check my ans.  I was forget to convert it  [array objectAtIndex:0] into String. please replace your code

Comment: Thank you once again Prateek. I edited my code which works like a charm and one more question if you want. I edited my attempts for the answer method.Take a look and if you want tell me how to convert the read of the two number on equal. I mean that on column two of database i have the right answer. Thank you in advance i really apreciate your help.

Comment: I am sorry Prateek i haven't seen that i am not saved the changes on edit. Now i placed the answer method on the post and send it to your email on a txt file.